# I need to understand some hexadecimal notation

Tags: hex, gml

I have to do some bitwise operations to perform collision checking for my game, but, I've stumbled into some hexadecimal notation I don't know.

Example from: http://www.yoyogames.com/tech_blog/7

> Using the binary tricks above, we can do a simple AND with Y coordinate
>
> ```
> Y = Y & $fffffff0
> ```
>
> , and this will rid us of the lower bits making the value a multiple of 16, and placing it outside the collision, and back to 64; since
>
> ```
> %1001000 (68) & $fffffff0 = %1000000 (64).
> ```

Another formula, from: http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=552034

```
$fffffff0 = 4294967280 = ~$F = ~15
$ffffffe0 = 4294967264 = ~$1F = ~31
```

What kind of hexadecimal notation is this? What does the '$' mean?

Answer (score 1):

`~` is the operator for bitwise operation `NOT`. What it does is invert all bits. 0 become 1 and 1 become 0.

`$` preceeding the value tells the compiler its an hexadecimal number. Without it, `fffffff0` would be understood as being a variable name.

So you see while `15` means `15` decimal and `f` hexadecimal, `$15` is `15` hexadecimal and `21` decimal.